# Align volume panel to right

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, video.js

I need to align volumePanel to the right corner. It seems API hasn't this functionality, so, I've done a lot of attempts on CSS, but it doesn't want to move :( I've built a ready-to-work [template](https://codesandbox.io/s/videojs-volumebar-right-4cj7iy) at codesandbox. Help me, please.

Comment: but the volume panel is already in the right corner , anyway i think this can help document.getElementById('vjs-control-bar").setAttribute('dir', 'rtl')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS rule to set the volumePanel to the right. As this is a component, make sure you don't use a scoped style tag but a regular style tag

```
<style>
  .vjs-control-bar {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: end;
}
</style>
```

[You should get this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H53Dd.png)

Comment: Thank you much! Spent an hour on this :( Saved my day, man!

Comment: You are welcome man! Make sure to mark it as the answer or upvote it, so everyone else knows too!

Answer (score 0):

You must create your own custom skin to place elements as you wish and style them as you wish. VideoJS has a documentation for that and there are plenty of websites that let you customize a skin.

see this : https://www.scriptsmashup.com/Video_Skin_Generator/Videojs/videojs-skin-generator.html